# Fetch Array Value if another Array Value equals to x

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

Let's say I have a JS `array` that looks like this:

```
"transactionProducts": [
      {
        "name": "Product A",
        "price": 100
      },
      {
        "name": "Product B",
        "price": 1000
      }
    ]
```

I would like to return the value of Price only **when the value of Name contains B or Product B**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.find()` and `String.prototype.match()`, like so:

```js
let transactionProducts = [{
  "name": "Product A",
  "price": 100
}, {
  "name": "Product B",
  "price": 1000
}];

let price = (transactionProducts.find(x => x.name.match('B'))||{price: undefined}).price;

console.log(price);
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this will throw an error `cannot read property price of undefined` if no item matches.

Comment: @chŝdk Good call, fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can `.filter()` array first and then use `.map()` to get prices only:

```js
let strArray = ['B', 'Product B'];
let data = [{ "name": "Product A", "price": 100 },{ "name": "Product B", "price": 1000 }];

let result = data.filter(({ name }) => strArray.some(s => name.includes(s)))
                 .map(({ price }) => price);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
function returnPrice(obj) {
    if (obj["name"].match(/B/)) {
        return obj["price"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `obj["name"].includes("B") || obj["name"].includes("Product B")` is the same as writing `obj["name"].includes("B")`.

Comment: Whoops, you're right @chŝdk

Comment: Would this be specific to that transactionProduct array?

Comment: Yes @TvZ I could change it if you give me an example array and inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thanks @JackBashford - the array name (transactionProducts) is correct. When testing it in Google Tag Manager and in Chrome Console, it returns undefined. 

The reason for the script is that I need to return the price of a product if the name of that product includes a specific brand i.e. Apple. This should be if there is a single product in the array or multiple. This array sit within a Google Tag Manager dataLayer.